# how to show 1st TAB Active by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i am having two Tabs TAB 1 and TAB 2. Now i want to show TAB 1 by default Active when i load page everytime . how should i do that ? I am using jquery Mobile to develope an application for mobile.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('div[data-role="navbar"] a').live('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
    $('div.content_div').hide();
    $('div#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
    });
    </script>

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-href="a" class="tabbs " >TAB 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-href="b" class="tabbs" >TAB 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    <div id="a" class="content_div"> </div>
    <div id="b" class="content_div" > </div>
```

Thanx In Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to first element to make it active on doucment.ready. You will have to de-select the previously selected tab in click event as well.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jxwZ2/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    prevTab = $('div[data-role="navbar"] a');    
    prevTab.eq(0).addClass('ui-btn-active'); //Selects first tab.

     $('div[data-role="navbar"] a').live('click', function () {
       prevTab.removeClass('ui-btn-active'); 
       $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
       $('div.content_div').hide();
       $('div#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
       prevTab = $(this);
     });

</script>
```

Comment: I have added live demo, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the `ui-btn-active` class to the first tab in the HTML and another class to show the content div?

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YEqBh/1/ (edited the jQuery a bit too) (oops updated link)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).load()`
give `ul` an **id**. Then using that **id** find the first children and add the class with it.. It will work nicely.

```
$(window).load(function{
$('UL_ID li: first-child').addClass('class_Name');
});
```